# python/pandas "Kernel died, restarting" while loading a csv file

Tags: python, pandas, kernel

While trying to load a big csv file (150 MB) I get the error "Kernel died, restarting". Then only code that I use is the following:

```
import pandas as pd
from pprint import pprint
from pathlib import Path
from datetime import date
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

basedaily = pd.read_csv('combined_csv.csv')
```

Before it used to work, but I do not know why it is not working anymore. I tried to fixed it using engine="python" as follows:

```
basedaily = pd.read_csv('combined_csv.csv', engine='python')
```

But it gives me an error execution aborted.

Any help would be welcome!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It may be because of the lack of memory you got this error. You can split your data in many data frames, do your work than you can re merge them, below some useful code that you may use:

```
import pandas as pd

# the number of row in each data frame
# you can put any value here according to your situation
chunksize = 1000

# the list that contains all the dataframes
list_of_dataframes = []

for df in pd.read_csv('combined_csv.csv', chunksize=chunksize):
    # process your data frame here
    # then add the current data frame into the list
    list_of_dataframes.append(df)

# if you want all the dataframes together, here it is
result = pd.concat(list_of_dataframes)
```

Comment: Give it a try and tell me the result @francis, please!

Comment: Hey @Sidou Mahmoud I have been using your technique and it works. I really dont know why it stopped working as before, do you have an idea why this happened? Will I be forced to always do this chunk procedure from now and in the future? Also how can I call data that is in the middle of my csv file? because this chunk size just call the first observations isn't? Thank you!

Comment: I advise you to load just the first df in my previous code and see if it goes, then start increasing data frame to ensure that it is a memory problem. Read this documentation also : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html